# Honour module's `config.yml` when dynamically importing modules into Snakemake workflow

Tags: snakemake

### Background

I'm new to scientific workflows, and am building my first more complex Snakemake workflow.

### Setup & what I've tried

I'm importing modules *dynamically*. The scenario is that I have a root `config.yml` file that includes:

```yaml
subworkflows:
 - subwf-1
 - subwf-2
 - other-subwf
```

In the root `Snakefile` I'm doing:

```py
configfile: 'config.yml'

ALL_SUBWFS = config['subworkflows']

# <omitted> Check for min version 6.0

for MODULE in ALL_SUBWFS:

    module MODULE:
        snakefile:
            f'subworkflows/{MODULE}/Snakefile'

    use rule * from MODULE as f'{MODULE}_*'
```

This works fine so far. *However*, I'd like to be able to configure the different submodules each in their own `config.yml`.

Assume the following directory structure:

```bash
.
├── Snakefile
├── config.yml
└── subworkflows/
    ├── subwf-1/
    │   ├── Snakefile
    │   └── config.yml
    ├── subwf-2/
    │   ├── Snakefile
    │   └── config.yml
    └── other-subwf/
        ├── Snakefile
        └── config.yml
```

As far as I understand, this isn't supported, and neither of these options work:

- Define `configfile: config.yml` in main workflow and `configfile: cf` in subworkflows, where I've tried three options for `cf`:

```py
cf = str(workflow.source_path('config.yml'))  # 1
cf = f'{workflow.basedir}/config.yml'  # 2
cf = 'config.yml'  # 3

# With each of these options
configfile: cf
```

All give me `KeyError in <...>/Snakefile: 'config'`.

- Using `config: config` in module import, and subworkflows' `Snakefile`s including something like `VALUES = config['values']` gives me `KeyError in <...>/Snakefile: 'values'` using each option.

### Actual question

Am I right in assuming that it isn't possible to honour the `configfile`s for modules at all, and that instead, I need to use a global config file, e.g. with keys for each subworkflow imported as `config: config['<key-for-subworkflow-config-YAML-map>']`?

Comment: Another issue I've stumbled across is, that when I just let the subworkflows' `Snakefile` do `print('Hello from <name of subwf>')`, dynamically loading the modules seems to work fine.

However when I access actual `config['<key>']` from within the subworkflow, and have configured `config: config[f'{MODULE}']` on module import, only one subworkflow gets run.

Comment: I wonder if you really need to *dynamically* include the modules into your Snakefile? (Careful: `snakemake` has the option to include other workflows as `subworkflow`, which has been deprecated for some time, and as `modules`). I can also not imagine a situation where you want to dynamically change the included workflows. Are you sure this is a reasonable approach to take for your application? Or would standard `Snakefile`'s and rule dependencies also work? Note that you can also split your Snakefile into multiple parts without creating independent workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Further experimentation seems to show that my dynamic import of modules doesn't work: While `print()`ing from the subworkflow Snakefiles works fine, onyl one of the subworkflows gets executed when rules are defined.

This renders the question unanswerable at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your *Actual question*:

Rather than trying to pass or overwrite `configfile` you can try the intended approach for module of passing/overwriting the `config` dictionary used by the module.
The keyword here is `config: <dict>` in the `module <name>:` block which you might be able to combine with the `load_config` method of `snakemake:

```py
from snakemake.io import load_configfile

for MODULE in ALL_SUBWFS:

    module MODULE:
        snakefile: f'subworkflows/{MODULE}/Snakefile'
        config: load_configfile(f'subworkflows/{MODULE}/config.yml'
```

Note: Untested as you report other issues with your idea for loading external workflows dynamically.